# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. 1 2 3 ) into type

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm getting an error when I try to deserialize a JSON string:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) ...

vb.net code:

```
Public Class DATA
    Public Property CPU As String
End Class

Dim data As DATA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DATA)(File.ReadAllText("laptop.json"))
TextBox25.Text = DATA.CPU
```

The JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "spec": "CPU";
    "value": "Intel Core i3-4005U"
  };
  {
    "spec": "Speed";
    "value": "1.7 GHz"
  };
  {
    "spec": "Cache";
    "value": "3MB"
  };
  {
    "spec": "RAM";
    "value": "4GB"
  };
  {
    "spec": "Warranty Period";
    "value": "1 Year"
  }
]
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: First each item in the json is made of 2 values: "spec" and :"value" so your `Data` class is incomplete and backwards (CPU is a property *value*); Second, the json contains several of those objects which is what the error message is telling you.  It also tells you how to fix the error if you read the whole thing

Comment: That JSON is actually invalid: it has semicolons (`;`) separating the objects and values rather than commas (`,`).

Comment: Plutonix: i understand now and i deleted all data with spec and value and only one spec and one value in the json file but the same error

Comment: Brian Rogers: yes i fixed it but the error still exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three problems here.

First, the JSON as you have shown it is invalid.  Properties within JSON objects and values within JSON arrays must be separated by commas (`,`), not semicolons (`;`).  See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).

Second, your JSON represents an array (or list) of items, but you are trying to deserialize into a single class.  You need to deserialize into a list like this:

```
Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("laptop.json")
Dim list As List(Of DATA) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of DATA))(json)
```

Third, the property names in the `DATA` class you are using do not match the JSON property names of the objects in the array.  The class should be defined like this instead:

```
Class DATA
    Public Property spec As String
    Public Property value As String
End Class
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0aI2C3